# Como guardar una imagen en Base de datos por la URL

Tags: java, postgresql

Tengo una base de datos en Postgresql y usando pgadmin4, alli tengo una tabla llamada productos con 5 columnas que contienen los siguientes tipos de datos: Id, nombre, descripcion, precio, tipo. Ahora quiero añadir una columna donde pueda guardar una imagen desde su url para mostrar en mi proyecto un listado de productos donde tenagn todos una imagen y las descripciones del producto. Esto lo estoy trabajando en eclipse, quiero saber que tipo de dato seria la imagen y como la inserto en la base de datos. gracias

mi codigo:

```
@RequestMapping ("/sakuraproductos")
    static public String listadoProductos(Model template) throws SQLException {

    Connection connection;

    connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
            "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/blabla", "blablas",
            "blabla");

    PreparedStatement ps = connection
            .prepareStatement(

            "SELECT * FROM productos");

    ResultSet result = ps.executeQuery();

    ArrayList<Producto> listaProductos;

    listaProductos = new ArrayList<Producto>();

    while (result.next()) {

        Producto a = new Producto(result.getString("nombre"),
                result.getString("descripcion"),
                result.getDouble("precio"), result.getString("tipo")

        );

        listaProductos.add (a);

    }

    template.addAttribute("productos", listaProductos);

    connection.close();
    return "sakuraproductos";
}
```

Comment: Si es por url, podría ser String en java y character varying en postgres

Comment: gracias, como lo insertaria en pgadmin? Mi tabla es productos y mi columna es imagen, el queytool como seria?

Comment: gracias, ya lo resolvi!! era asi, al parecer:

Comment: UPDATE productos SET imagen = '{http://recetasdeviajes.com/wp-              content/uploads/2011/09/i5569_1.jpg}'
WHERE nombre= 'Pasta frola de membrillo'

Comment: Para decidir el tipo de dato, es muy importante que leas la [documentación](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.4/static/jdbc-binary-data.html) porque hay varios detalles a tener en cuenta. En cuanto a la forma de insertarla, [aquí tienes los mismos ejemplos de la documentación](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/80/binary-data.html). Otra posibilidad sería almacenar sólo las rutas de las imágenes, y los archivos en sí en alguna carpeta de tu proyecto, construyendo las rutas de cada imagen de forma dinámica, de esa forma no se carga tanto a la base de datos.

Answer (score 1):

Entiendo que la aplicación que deseas desarrollar es de tipo web (war). De preferencia las imágenes puden ser **PNG** ya que no son pesadas, debes decirle a tu componente que solo admita ese tipo de imagen. La idea de guardar solo la URL en una columna de la base de datos es correcta.

Con URL me refiero a que debes tener algo así guardado en el campo:

```
http://[nombre-de-tu-host]/[directorio-donde-esta-la-img]/imagen.png
```

Por ejemplo en tu base en la tabla respectiva, en el campo de la dirección debe estar un valor así:

```
(1) http://localhost/imagenes/imagen1.png
ó
(2) http://192.168.1.105/imagenes/producto1/imagen-p1.png
```

La imagen física debe estar guardada en algún servidor (en el mismo o en otro lugar), al cual le puedes instalar un ***Apache*** para que tus imágenes las puedas acceder desde un browser y así llamar a las imagenes por su URL.

Ahora independiente del framework para el front-end que estás utilizando, este debe ser capaz de generar en la página donde está el listado, la etiqueta:

```
<img>
```

La cual recibe como argumento la URL que está guardada en la base de datos y ese valor va en su atributo ***src***.

Lo que necesitas hacer en java sería generar el *CRUD* donde estará el método que permite guardar la imagen, hay varios ejemplos en la web de persistir datos.
Ahora para mostrar cada imagen por cada producto sería de que tengas en la pagina web (HTML) un componente *table* con un iterador el cual representa el objeto que mapea a tu entidad de la base de datos. Y en la columna donde va la imagen, le pones su atributo direccion.